# Web service - Unable to tunnel through proxy

Tags: web-services, myeclipse

I am using myeclipse to generate web service client. I change my network connection to Native (Use proxy address) but still am getting this error:
"unable to tunnel through proxy. proxy returns http/1.0 504"

Any solution for this?

Comment: Try running the client outside of MyEclipse to see if you get the same error. If so, it might be a problem with the proxy server.

Comment: Yes i try to run it using wsimport via command prompt. I still get this error. When I run it with SOAPUI,it works fine. I don't think it's the proxy. Do i need to code to handle the proxy in java?

Comment: If you are generating the client in these two ways and get the error in both cases, then it doesn't seem to be a MyEclipse issue, as such. Sorry, I can't help more. Hopefully, someone with experience in web services will be able to help.